# Dynamic routing with next export mode

Tags: react-router, next.js, url-routing, static-site-generation

We're using Next.Js in [next export mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) (static HTML export), and we need advanced dynamic routing.

Our routes will look like `/[config1]/[config2]/[optionalConfig?]/page`, where one segment is optional and the page names are fixed. For example `a/b/c/page1` or `a1/b1/page2`. The pages need the configuration segment data to render.

I haven't found any way to do this with the [built-in routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). I can do `/pages/[config1]/[config2]/page1.tsx`, but that optional segment seems to be an issue. Note that a custom server does not appear to be an option, as we have to use next export mode due to other constraints.

**NOTE:** We don't know the paths at build time; they represent part of our runtime configuration. This *has* to use client-side routing. (We *do* know the finite set of pages - say page1 ... page10 - but the routes to those pages will vary.)

I've tried switching to React Router, setting `useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false` and adding routes to `pages/_app.tsx` (Custom App). That *almost* works, but I see many 404s for `on-demand-entries-utils.js` in the console as well as some "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected" warnings (in development mode).

Valid solutions (must work 100% client-side):

- Way to do this with built-in routing
- Example of integrating React Router with Next.Js
- Alternative library (I've looked at [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes) but that hasn't been updated in 3 years)

**UPDATE**

We may be able to eliminate the requirement of an optional segment. However, it appears that we have to implement `getStaticPaths` and specify all of the routes. For example:

**pages/[config]/foo.tsx**

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Runs at build time
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { config: 'xyz' } }],
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}

export default function FooPage(): JSX.Element {
  return <div>FOO</div>;
}
```

This will generate

```
┌ ○ /
├   /_app
├ ● /[config]/foo
├   └ /xyz/foo
```

The issue is that ***we do not know the config at build time.***

We need dynamic client-side routing. We'd like to stay with Next.js, as *eventually* we may be able to use SSR, but that's not an option at the moment.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the built-in [optional catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes).

Comment: @juliomalves Catch-all only works with page names, not directory names. I could probably make a catch-all page, then conditionally render component "pages" based on the query object, but that seems like a hack.

Comment: It would generate pages for whatever paths you'd define in `getStaticPaths`. You just have to make sure that `getStaticProps` then handles the params (passed by `getStaticPaths`) correctly when generating those pages.

Comment: @juliomalves We don't know the paths at build time.

Comment: How are you using static HTML export with dynamic routes then? That's done at build time.

Comment: @juliomalves It appears that we can't use Next.Js dynamic routes. The app is still in development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232255/discussion-between-truewill-and-juliomalves).

Comment: I built my whole app assuming that dynamic routes would work on export based on them working in dev glad I’m not the only one running up against this. This is super unintuitive, Based on the number of issues I’m seeing around this there should be a huge disclaimer on next.js docs “DYNAMIC ROUTES DO NOT ROUTE DYNAMICALLY ON EXPORT” or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a catch-all route to grab the parameters, including the optional one, and then you'll need to render the right component based on that. So if you created:

```js
pages/[...config].tsx
```

This is the same as:

```js
pages/[...config]/index.tsx
```

Then in `index.tsx`, you can get the config as an array of strings in `getStaticProps` based on the url. So `/config1/config2/optional` is `[config1, config2, optional]` and `/config1/config2` is `[config1, config2]`.

So you can use this as a directory path of sorts if you need to add additional subpages under the known and optional paths.

Comment: Unfortunately I've learned that dynamic routes don't work with static HTML export unless you predefine the paths at build time - and we don't know that. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Then you only have three options - 1) make those pages server side rendered which you said is not an option, 2) spin that portion of your app off into a separate single-page application with something like create react app and react router (not ideal), or 3) use url parameters instead of url paths - myapp.com/?config1=foo&config2=bar, etc and then read those in a `useEffect` in next to ping your server. We do this on an e-comm site for order history. The users don't care - it's just us devs that hate it.

Comment: Sounds like 2 is our only option - the others won't be acceptable to our stakeholders. Thanks.

Comment: That sucks because it's definitely the most labor intensive and probably the one most prone to bugs and integration problems. I'd definitely advocate for #1 or #3 if possible, but good luck however it works out!

Comment: I think you nailed it with your three options. We confirmed with someone from Vercel that this isn't going to work with next export. Putting React Router in a custom 404 page works for option 2, but it's a hack. https://github.com/brajevicm/next-universal-route#readme is a maybe.

Comment: I searched so long for this option 3!! we were using useEffect fetching data based on params so this requires minimal change when exporting to static (also specify `module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}` in `next.config.js`) , it's perfect.